# What is a 'view' in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

There are a number of references to something called a `view` in the ExpressJS documentation. For example, the first argument of `res.render` is a `view`, for example `'index'`. What is a `view`?

Comment: Hard to explain without using the word -- it's what it sounds like. It's the view file for whatever rendering engine you use. Default is Jade (I believe) - so `index` would be `index.jade` located in the default views folder (views)

Comment: http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/

Comment: You will bump into this concept in many web frameworks: [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 1):

The `view` in express would be the template so to speak that the app would use to render the pages. So that you could supply a particular template to render all pages to say `/about` using the `about` view.

Answer (score 0):

"view" in express.js is just a template file, nothing more than that.